# how to generate this matrix in latex?

Tags: matrices

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\env@matrix[1][*\c@MaxMatrixCols c]{%
  \hskip -\arraycolsep
  \let\@ifnextchar\new@ifnextchar
  \array{#1}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \begin{bmatrix}[cc|c|c]
0 & -I & I & 0\\
0 & 0 & -I & I \\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is your image the matrix you want?  Or the matrix you get?  What does your code snippet do?  Could you make it a complete example by including the necessary `\usepackage` and document commands?

Comment: here you go, i modified it. i was just able to generate like the right matrix in the picture but i need the left one.

Answer (score 2):

You can't get those matrices just with `bmatrix`, but you need to use the lower level `array`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,booktabs}

\begin{document}

\[
\mathbf{L}=
\begin{bmatrix}
\begin{array}{@{}cc@{}}
\mathbf{I} & \mathbf{0} \\
\mathbf{0} & \mathbf{I} \\
\midrule[\arrayrulewidth]
\mathbf{0} & \mathbf{I} \\
\midrule[\arrayrulewidth]
\mathbf{0} & \mathbf{I}
\end{array}
\end{bmatrix}
\implies
\mathbf{L}^+=
\begin{bmatrix}
\begin{array}{@{}cc|c|c@{}}
\mathbf{I} & \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{0} \\
\mathbf{0} & \mathbf{I} & \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{0}
\end{array}
\end{bmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: when i adding ` \begin{equation}` `  \end{equation}` does not work. it seems not possible to put in one equation.

Comment: @user224189 You need to *replace* `\[` with `\begin{equation}` and `\]` with `\end{equation}`.